# Now that TrueSwitch has been shutdown, how can I import emails from Gmail to Outlook.com?

Tags: gmail, migration, outlook.com

I'm in the process of migrating from Gmail to Outlook.com, following the steps described in [this tutorial](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-outlook/archive/2012/08/09/upgrade-from-gmail-to-outlook-com-in-5-easy-steps.aspx). The last step is to import the old emails from Gmail to Outlook.com, using [TrueSwitch](http://www.trueswitch.com/). Unfortunately, I realized that TrueSwitch has been shutdown since the tutorial was published.

Is there a good alternative to TrueSwitch?

I've seen [YippieMove](http://www.yippiemove.com/), which is not free; I'm willing to pay if it's worth the price, but I have no idea how good it is.

If there is no good online solution, is there a PC-based tool I could use?

Comment: How about downloading all your emails from gmail to a desktop mail client like Thunderbird and then copying or moving all the folders from one account to the other? Also, since your question deals for the most part with web services, someone is likely to downvote or close it. Please rephrase it to make it more software-oriented.

Comment: @user99572isfine, I started doing exactly that, but I'm afraid it will take a very long time... I just realized there is a [webapps.se] SE website, perhaps I should have posted there.

Comment: If you are willing to use Linux for a short time, this is exact reason [FetchMail](http://fetchmail.berlios.de/) was created. FetchMail pulls emails from one server and pushes them to another using IMAP, POP3, and SMTP. Free, Open Source, and well documented, I've used FetchMail for all my mail server migrations.

Comment: @MarkLopez, thanks, but I already found a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here's what I did eventually:

1. installed Windows Live Mail
2. configured my Gmail account using IMAP
3. configured my Outlook.com account using the Hotmail protocol (whatever it is)
4. dragged my messages from the Gmail folders to the Outlook.com folders
5. let it run the whole night

I now have all my Gmail messages on Outlook.com

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be setup imapsync:
We use it here for big migrations, assuming you are migrating from gmail I can bet you have a huge amount of data.

Here is a tutorial of how to use it:
http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-migrate-mailboxes-between-imap-servers-with-imapsync

Hm seems you cannot use it in outloo.

> Failure stories reported with the following 3 imap servers:
>
> ```
>  - MailEnable 1.54 (Proprietary) but MailEnable 4.23 is supported. 
>  - DBMail 0.9, 2.0.7 (GPL). But DBMail 1.2.1 is supported.
>    Patient and confident testers are welcome.
>  - Imail 7.04 (maybe).
>  - (2011) MDaemon 12.0.3 as host2 but MDaemon is supported as host1.
>    MDaemon is simply buggy with the APPEND IMAP command with 
>    any IMAP email client.
>  - Hotmail since hotmail.com does not provide IMAP access
>  - Outlook.com since outlook.com does not provide IMAP access
> ```

According to here:
http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090709000633AAJXg6o
you can
Go into Settings, then into POP/Mail forwarding and (assuming you're using POP) click the 'Enable POP for all mail (even mail that's already been downloaded)' button then hit 'Send/Receive' in Outlook. it will download every message ever received in your Gmail account.

Comment: Thanks, but as you noticed yourself, Outlook.com doesn't support IMAP (which is a shame, and one of the things that made me hesitate to migrate). I'm trying something that seems to be working, I'll post my solution if everything goes well.

Comment: Outlook.com actually does support IMAP now http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-outlook/archive/2013/09/12/outlook-com-now-with-imap.aspx and these instructions should work, making this an awesome answer. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

## IMAP Tools Light for Python3

Users attempting to move/copy/migrate IMAP email accounts might find my python script useful. It is open source and I tried to make it easy to use - also for people who don't use commandline tools very often, as the tools commonly available require quite a bit of configuration and tweaking.

### Example of simple 1-line command to solve your question:

(you will be prompted for login details)

```
python3 imap_tools_light.py -a MIGRATE GMAIL OUTLOOK
```

The downside compared to services such as YippieMove or TrueSwitch is that you have to run the script locally (your pc needs to be on for the whole process of moving emails and your internet connection is subjected to rather high traffic, depending on the size of your mailboxes).

However, it is far easier and less hassle than trying to copy paste your emails in Thunderbird or in Windows Live Mail clients, a solution which uses even more of your local resources and, more importantly, a lot more of your time.

But bare in mind that OUTLOOK.COM's new IMAP server implementation is currently having huge problems with mailboxes containing more than a couple of thousand messages. See e.g. [this thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/mail-email/imap-throws-error-9-server-error-when-fetching/0c3bbff0-75c8-4a40-ba60-7669fb7da659) for further details.

So I'd suggest waiting until this issue 'Error 9' is solved by Microsoft.

### Complete install procedure to get the script running on Ubuntu:

The script is open source and can be downloaded from: https://bitbucket.org/mki5600/imap_python3

Dependencies: Python3, imapclient (which can be installed using pip)

Make sure that Python3 is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

Make sure that Pip is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Install imapclient, using pip:

```
sudo pip3 install imapclient
```

Download and extract Script.

Open Terminal in script directory ...

```
../imap_tools_light/$
```

and type:

```
python3 imap_tools_light.py -a MIGRATE GMAIL OUTLOOK
```

or

```
python3 imap_tools_light.py -h
```

for options and help.

Answer (score -1):

Very easy to do this now. Make an outlook hotmail account online. 
options
import email account
put in your gmail account
approve authorisation
all your gmail emails come through into your new outlook account.